# Grails - Spring security - session settings

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

When user directly accessing some restricted url, for the first time, with out login, spring security redirects to login page. If the login is success, the user is redirected to the requested page.Between the user login success and page redirection to requested page, how to initialize user specific settings in http session. What events are available to set the session with logged in user details.

EDIT:

My intention is not save the user details in the session. Depends on the user, i have to change the displayed content before it goes to some other page after login.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do that - it's a waste of server memory and will affect scalability. Get out of the habit of storing lots of unnecessary data in the session.

The `Authentication` class that the plugin uses caches the id of the `User`/`Person` domain class instance that was used during login. So it's easy to reload the domain class instance - just call `def user = springSecurityService.currentUser`. This approach has the added benefit of avoiding lazy loading exceptions and other problems with detached Hibernate objects.